# Is it a bug in TransformedDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I worked with

```
CDF[TransformedDistribution[1/x, x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3]], t]
(*Piecewise[{{2^(-1 + Ceiling[1/t])
 3^(-2 - Ceiling[1/t]) (18 + 7 Ceiling[1/t] + Ceiling[1/t]^2),t > 0}}, 0]*)
```

The result is very doubtful in view of

```
Limit[%, t -> Infinity]
(*26/27*)
```

(As I know, it must be 1.)
and

```
DistributionDomain[NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3]]
(*0 ;; \[Infinity]*)
```

Don't I understand something?

Comment: Is it even valid to do transform to 1/x when you know the `NegativeBinomialDistribution` has zero in the support? `DistributionDomain[NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3]]` gives `0;;Infinity`. If you do 1/(x+1), then the limit works and gives 1.

Comment: `$Assumptions = e > 0;
cdf = CDF[
   TransformedDistribution[1/(x + e), 
    x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3]], t];
Limit[cdf, t -> Infinity]` . This gives 1 too assuming e is positive non-zero.

Comment: I'm going to agree with flinty here. Asking for a transformed distribution where the transformation isn't defined for all values in the distribution domain is asking for trouble. Especially for discrete distributions where there will always be a finite positive amount of probability mass on the ill-defined point.

Comment: The user may not know the domain of the transformed distribution, may he/she?  Also `Limit[CDF[
  TransformedDistribution[1/(x + e), 
   x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3], 
   Assumptions -> e > 0], t], e -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` still performs an incorrect result.

Comment: @user64494 Does the distribution you're asking for even exist? I don't see how it could, to be honest.

Comment: @SjoerdSmith: Compare with `CDF[TransformedDistribution[1/x, 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]], t];Limit[%,t->Infinity]`. which performs $1$.

Comment: @user64494 yes obviously the normal distribution would work because the probability of precisely zero is almost surely zero. It's a continuous distribution. The problem with your distribution is it is discrete and has non-vanishing probability of zero, so you can't do 1/x to it.

Comment: @flinty: In any case, the command should not produce an incorrect result.

Comment: @user64494 Yes I would say that for discrete distributions, any attempt to do `TransformedDistribution` that would result in singularities should really give `$Failed` instead of a misleading answer.

Comment: Also `Mean[TransformedDistribution[1/(x), 
  x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3]]]` performs `2/27`, whereas `Mean[TransformedDistribution[1/(x), 
  x \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]]]` results in `Indeterminate`.

Comment: @flinty I'll create a suggestion bugreport to that effect.

Comment: @flinty: BTW, `Mean[TransformedDistribution[1/(x), 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]]` returns the input.

Comment: The downvoters: Mathematica would not become better by your votes. It is impossible to avoid bugs in the soft which takes  approximately 10GB. BTW, several previous bug reports of me were rejected by WTS as a spam.

Comment: `% /. t -> Infinity` returns `1`. I don't understand why you took the limit.

Comment: @NichaelE2: Sorry, `Infinity` is not a real number, E.g. `n/(n + 1) /. n -> Infinity` returns `Indeterminate`.

Comment: Sorry, your transformation is nonsense if your universe is confined to the real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Let ${\Bbb N}$ be the nonnegative integers.
Let $R = \{1/n\colon n \in {\Bbb N}\}$, where $1/0$ is identified with a point at (positive) infinity.
Let $T=g(X)$ where $g \colon {\Bbb N} \rightarrow R$, $g(x) = 1/x$.  Then the characteristic property of the transformed distribution is that for any $A \subset R$,
$$\def\set#1{\{#1\}}
P\set{T\in A}=P\set{g(X) \in A}=P\set{X \in g^{-1}(A)}\,.
$$
The transformed distribution produced by

```
TransformedDistribution[1/x, x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3]]
```

satisfies this property. If we define $g(0)$ to be `Infinity` so that $g(0) > g(1) > g(2) > \cdots$, then all operates as it should in Mathematica.  Note however that in Mathematica `1/0` evaluates to `ComplexInfinity`.  This causes problems with the `PDF` and `CDF` because `ComplexInfinity > 1` etc. are invalid comparisons.  To me this seems an inevitable problem because of the way Mathematica works over the complex numbers.

Note that the limit of a function $f(t)$, $t \in R$, as $t \rightarrow \infty$, is not well defined. The infinite point $t=1/0$ is not a limit point of $R$.  I'm not sure if Mathematica should be responsible for that, or if it should be treated as user GIGO.  (For Mathematica to do that, each variable would have to carry metadata specifying its domain and topology.  It would be cool if it did, kind of like a hammer that guided itself to the nail each time.  But maybe the user needs to take responsibility for aiming the tool sometimes.)

Comment: Sorry, I prtefer arguments over ungrouded words. There are other problems with the distribution under consideration. E.g. `Limit[Mean[
  TransformedDistribution[1/(x + c), 
   x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3], 
   Assumptions -> c > 0]], c -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` produces `1/27 (6 + Log[3])` instead of `ComplexInfinity`.

Comment: @user64494 Sorry, that is not the problem under consideration. Please read the OP.

Comment: MichaelE2 (@does not work): But  a related one.

Comment: MichaelE2: My question is motivated by [that question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375448/finding-the-expectation-mathrme-1-x-for-a-negative-binomial-random-varia/375454#375454).

Comment: @user64494 (No need for @ when the user is the author of the post you are commenting on.) I don't understand why you expect `ComplexInfinity` instead of `1/27 (6 + Log[3]`.  That statement is unfounded.

Comment: Michael E2, the positive distribution `TransformedDistribution[1/(x + c),     x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3],     Assumptions -> c > 0]]` takes, in particular,  the value `1/c` with  some postive probability which does not depend on $c$. Therefore, its mean should to  tend to infinity, as $c$ tends to zero.

Comment: @user64494 More particularly, the problem is with the limit of Lerch phi function: `Limit[LerchPhi[2/3, 1, c], c -> 0]` should be infinite, even though `LerchPhi[2/3, 1, 0]` is finite.

Comment: Michael E2: Thank you for your shedding  light on the problem. You saw the heart of the problem.

Comment: @user64494 You're welcome. BTW, if you remove `Assumptions -> c > 0`, then the `Mean` is in terms of `HurwitzLerchPhi`, and the `Limit` error is avoided, in case you need a workaround.

Comment: The assumption `Assumptions -> c > 0` is necessary here to avoid division by zero, This is not any workaround. I wonder the upvoter.

Comment: I mean `Mean[TransformedDistribution[1/(x + c), 
  x \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 1/3]]];%/.c->1` which produces `Indeterminate`. `Limit` works.